# Getting HTML <link> element's target content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a C interpreter written in javascript, which receive the C code as a string, like:

```
var object = c.compile('int func(int a) { return a*2; }');
```

Now I have some functions written in a bunch of C files:

- basic.c;
- data_process.c;
- ...

I'd like to put references to theses files in the html in a way that I can use the html both locally and on a http server. I thought of using the `<link>` element:

```
<link id="basic.c" href="basic.c" type="text/x-c; charset=utf-8">
<link id="data_process.c" href="data_process.c" type="text/x-c; charset=utf-8">
<!-- ... -->
```

Now I can get the `<link>` element with `document.getElementById('basic.c')`.

**But how can I get the contents of the href'd resource?**

Perhaps the `<link>` element is not the right one. But which one is right for the task?

Comment: `document.getElementById("basic.c").getAttribute("href")` ??

Comment: @GeorgeBailey this does not return the data behind the link, which is, I assume what the OP wants

Comment: Oh yeah it won't. I misunderstood it. I took it as if he was asking for `href` value etc

Comment: @Luca is right, I'd like to get the linked file contents (rather than it's url).

Comment: Take what @GeorgeBailey said and then use `fetch` to go get the content.  The browser won't load this content for you and populate a JavaScript scope automatically.

Comment: @zero298 even with `rel="preload"`? Also, I don't expect it to populate a js scope. I wonder if somehow that content is accessible on the element (DOM) itself.